# In terraform how should I use azure_function_endpoint

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-eventgrid

I have a terraform script to create: **Function App** and **Event Grid Topic** and **Event Grid Subscription** with a **Function** as an endpoint

```
resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "example" {
  ...
}
resource "azurerm_eventgrid_topic" "example" {
  ...
}
resource "azurerm_eventgrid_event_subscription" "example" {
  name  = "sub1"
  scope = azurerm_eventgrid_topic.example.id
  azure_function_endpoint {
    function_id = "${azurerm_linux_function_app.example.id}/functions/event-grid-example"
}
```

Obviously I'm getting "*Resource should pre-exist before attempting this operation*" as **event-grid-example** funcion does not exist yet. And it does not exist because I need to deploy my **Function** first. But I cannot deploy my **Function** before I terraform the infrastructure... Which I cannot do, because ... the **Function** is not there

How am I supposed to do it?

Comment: The provided config does not seem to match the behavior you are describing as a dependency is implicitly constructed. A plan snippet and the error message (especially whether it is returned from TF, the provider, or Azure) would be helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with eventgrid and Azure functions on Terraform. The problem stems from the eventgrid extension not being deployed on Azure functions until there is a function deployed with an eventgrid trigger (as you rightly pointed out).

The way I solved this was by using what I call a "Terraform sandwich". Add an input variable of type boolean called "enable subscriptions".

1. Run Terraform with "enable eg subscriptions" set to false.
2. Deploy your Terraform code.
3. Run Terraform with "enable eg subscriptions" set to true.

The second Terraform apply will work because your function code has been deployed with the eventgrid trigger code and is ready for you to setup subscriptions.

This will cause churn in your subscriptions so you will need to think about a brief outage window when deploying to production. To avoid this you can add logic in step one to check if the subscription already exists using Azure cli and pass true instead.

Comment: I was afraid this would be a solution :(
another option is to create the subscription in my function deploy code.
equally bad

Comment: I've also create a mock deployment that puts code with an event trigger in there and then override with the real code post provisioning. I've raised this as an issue as it does not make for a great automation story lazy loading the extensions. However until there is a way to explicitly define the extensions this is the only way. :(

Comment: Could you give me the green check kind sir? 